# getting Empty src while scraping

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, scrapy, jsoup

I am trying to Scrape Contents of A website using Jsoup. The HTML parsed by Jsoup has empty src attribute (i.e src="") while the when I inspect website in chrome it shows non-empty src(It is not being filled with javascript). It is not just a problem with just Jsoup, Scrapy return same results(empty src).
I have tried adding custom user agent.

Can anybody tell what could be the reason of this problem and possible solutions.
*I can not use methods like selenium cause I am seeking solution for android app development.
Thanks!

Edit:

Site being used is flipkart.com i am scraping from its search result https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=xbox&marketplace=FLIPKART&sid=search.flipkart.com

Src from its "img" tag is being parsed empty.

Comment: It is hard to give you an answer without knowing the site you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I have updated my question please tell if anything else is missing. Thanks

Comment: I've come up with a soloution make sure to checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src attribute is empty. View Page Source in browser and search for the class. Then you will find the src attribute value empty. [image]

Comment: But it shows value when using inspection tools in browser. How can I scrape src in this case. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You may use [Selenium with Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) to scrape this `src` attribute.

```
#!/bin/bash/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=xbox&marketplace=FLIPKART&sid=search.flipkart.com")

elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//img[@class="_1Nyybr"]')

for element in elem:
    print element.get_attribute('src')
    print element.get_attribute('class')

driver.close()
```

**EDIT**

use `contains` to fetch the results.

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[contains(@class, "_30XEf0")]')
```

Comment: I can not use selenium. Like I said I am using Jsoup to scrape webpages in android application. But thanks.